# Openerp module web issue with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, odoo

I'm trying to make a web module that depends on a website module. I want to use a javascript file in my template but I can't. The tutorials that I find are very poor and I've tried to see the existing module but I can't understand it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/src/js/test.js"></script> 

I added this line in my template and I try to use function that defined in file js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hear In odoo 8.0 You can add the two different way to add the JavaScript file in your template view

**1. Add in as the TAG specify ::**

```
<template id="event_script" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="Country Events Snippet Script">
    <xpath expr="/t" position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_event/static/src/js/website_geolocation.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

**2. Add the inside the .(dot) specify ::**

```
<template id="assets_editor" inherit_id="website.assets_editor" name="Event Editor" groups="event.group_event_manager">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_event/static/src/js/website_event.editor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_event/static/src/js/website.tour.event.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

in the template has the

**id**  Attribute :> Unique  identify each record

**inherit_id**  Attribute :> Inherited template id which is specify in two different way

I.use the  direct id if for  the same module (template_id)

II.use with the inherited module template id (module_name.template_id)

And Also name and group all other attributes which are use in template

the based on the **XPATH Tag** **with position attribute** You can add your JavaScript file on different position like before,after,inside,replace

I hope this should helpful for you .. :)